# Missing separator error in Makefile no tab problems

Tags: makefile, separator

I can't figure where my code is wrong. I'm trying to launch the "make" command on a C++-project in windows prompt (I installed mingw-get-inst-20120426 on my pc) and it gives me back always the same error:

> Makefile:672: *** missing separator.  Stop.

This is the line 672 of my file:

```
        && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) DESTDIR="$$dc_destdir" uninstall \
```

I have check for hidden spaces in this line, but there are only tabs: I have no idea where the error is (I'm newbie to makefiles).
Can anybobody help me?
Thanks,
Stefano

Comment: Give us the whole target that includes that line (and possibly the target before and after it)?

Answer (score 0):

You should show the rest of the rule, not just that one line.  The problem is not on this line but on the lines before it.  I'll make a guess and say that either (a) you've forgotten to add a backslash at the end of the previous line, or (b) you have a backslash but then you've also added some extra whitespace or whatever after the backslash; the backslash must be the *last* character on the line to be recognized as a continuation character.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the variables `$(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS)` include leading or trailing spaces, please post the context of this line in your Makefile, as-well as the values used for those variables.

Edit: I had intended my answer to be: the contents of `$(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS)` likely include a trailing or leading space, thus causing this error.